# How to programatically close ContentDialog in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to programatically close the dialog with either primary or secondary button action from another button in the content dialog.

Answer (score 8):

you need to call Hide method to close the contentDialog from your button